# JQGrid sort by column works only after use pagination

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have an issue with jqgrid, I want the rows in my grid ordered by date from the most recent. I set in the grid options the column and the order but when the data are loaded, are displayed as they are loaded. The ordering works only after I click on the columns or if I use pagination, for example, if I go to page 2 and go back to page 1, or if I increase the number of rows in a page, they are ordered correctly.
This is the Date column by which I want the data to be ordered,

```
{
  name: 'DatetimeInserted',
  index: 'DatetimeInserted',
  width: "130",
  sortable: true, search: false,
  sorttype: "datetime",
  datefmt: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
  width: 200
},
```

These are the sorting options

```
sortname: "DatetimeInserted",
sortable: true,
sortorder: 'desc',
```

The data are passed in a json format to the jqgrid initializer
`Query(gridSelector).jqGrid({
 loadui: "block",
 data: jsonData.rows,
 datatype: "local",`

This is an example of JSON data returned from the server

```
{"rows":[{"Id":37,"CustomerId":126,"CustomerType":2,"SiteId":1,"DatetimeInserted":"2019-12-10T15:25:00","ValoSource":1,"ChatId":"","EmailInboundId":107,"WebPageUrl":"","WebPageTitle":"","IpAddress":"10.75.148.72","TicketId":"PNG00000258","RequestId":249,"AgentName":"Admin Admin","ChatState":""},{"Id":44,"CustomerId":126,"CustomerType":2,"SiteId":1,"DatetimeInserted":"2019-12-13T08:34:00","ValoSource":1,"ChatId":"","EmailInboundId":114,"WebPageUrl":"","WebPageTitle":"","IpAddress":"10.75.148.73","TicketId":"PNG00000334","RequestId":325,"AgentName":"Admin Admin","ChatState":""},{"Id":45,"CustomerId":126,"CustomerType":2,"SiteId":1,"DatetimeInserted":"2019-12-13T11:25:00","ValoSource":1,"ChatId":"","EmailInboundId":115,"WebPageUrl":"","WebPageTitle":"","IpAddress":"10.75.148.71","TicketId":"PNG00000335","RequestId":326,"AgentName":"Admin Admin","ChatState":""}]}
```

What am I missing? Thanks

EDIT: I tried calling `trigger("reloadGrid")` in `loadComplete` event, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround forcing a click on the first column manually after the call to the method that initializes the grid, but I'm not satisfied by this solution
`$("#jqgh_DatetimeInserted").trigger("click");
 $("#jqgh_DatetimeInserted").trigger("click");`